# Github Actions - Reading tokens from Secret File

Tags: github, azure-devops, github-actions, devops

I am trying to migrate a pipeline from Azure Devops to Github Actions. My project uses a lot of secrets which I have kept inside a file. In Azure Devops, I upload this file to "Secure Files" under library. I set the path of this file in Environment Variable. And I read the secrets in the file from my settings.gradle using the code below.

I was trying to figure out if I can do the same in Github actions - ie; upload the file containing all the secrets to github actions, and then read the secrets from gradle using the same code below.

I explored github actions documentation, but could not find anything that will help me read the secrets from a secure file as explained above.

I need to use this for multiple repositories, and I am trying to avoid a situation where I declare each of these variables one by one somewhere in github.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
final ENV_GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN ="GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN"
final ENV_KEY_FILE_PATH = "KEY_FILE_PATH"
final ENV_RELEASE_KEYSTORE_PASS = "RELEASE_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD"
final ENV_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS = "RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS"
final ENV_RELEASE_KEY_PASS = "RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD"
final ENV_MAVEN_REPO_URL = "MAVEN_REPO_URL"
final ENV_MAVEN_REPO_USERNAME = "MAVEN_REPO_USERNAME"
final ENV_MAVEN_REPO_PASSWORD = "MAVEN_REPO_PASSWORD"


Properties properties = new Properties()
File propertiesFile = new File(System.getenv(ENV_KEY_FILE_PATH) + "")
propertiesFile.withInputStream {
    properties.load(it)
}
gradle.ext.GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN = properties.get(ENV_GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN)
gradle.ext.MAVEN_REPO_URL = properties.get(ENV_MAVEN_REPO_URL)
gradle.ext.MAVEN_REPO_USERNAME = properties.get(ENV_MAVEN_REPO_USERNAME)
gradle.ext.MAVEN_REPO_PASSWORD = properties.get(ENV_MAVEN_REPO_PASSWORD)
gradle.ext.RELEASE_KEYSTORE_PASS = properties.get(ENV_RELEASE_KEYSTORE_PASS)
gradle.ext.RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS = properties.get(ENV_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS)
gradle.ext.RELEASE_KEY_PASS = properties.get(ENV_RELEASE_KEY_PASS)
```

Comment: Are those repos part of an org?

Comment: @Azeem yes, they are

Comment: If all those repos need those secrets then you may configure at org level. Regarding configuring the complete secrets file, you may configure all those secrets separated by newlines but then you'll have to inject those in the env context to be used by your scripts. Apart from injecting all of them, you may choose to configure them one by one at org level which will provide you more control over the individual secrets.

Comment: Helpful threads: [Migrating from Azure Pipelines to GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/migrating-to-github-actions/manual-migrations/migrating-from-azure-pipelines-to-github-actions) and [Migrating from Azure DevOps with GitHub Actions Importer](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/migrating-to-github-actions/automated-migrations/migrating-from-azure-devops-with-github-actions-importer)

Comment: @Azeem - I don't have access to Organization settings. As there are multiple teams in Organization.

Comment: Then, you need to set these secrets at repo level.